# Vigenere Cipher - Formula Explanation

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

First of all there is no one that I can ask this kind of question so please pardon me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    string key = argv[1];
    int l = strlen(argv[1]);
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i < n; i++) {
        if (!isalpha(key[i])) {
            return 0;
        }
        key[i] = tolower(key[i]);
        key[i] = key[i] - 97;
    }
    string txt = GetString();
    for (int k = 0, p = strlen(txt); k < p; k++) {
        if (isalpha(txt[k])) {
            if (isupper(txt[k])) {
                printf("%c", (((txt[k] - 65) + (key[k % l])) % 26 + 65));
            }
            if (islower(txt[k])) {
                printf("%c", (((txt[k] - 97) + (key[k % l])) % 26 + 97));
            }
        } else
        if (!isalpha(txt[k])) {
            printf("%c", txt[k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I can't quite get these 2 lines of code

```
key[i] = key[i] - 97;
printf("%c", (((txt[k] - 97) + (key[k % l])) % 26 + 97));
```

Is there an easy explanation of why did we use the first and how the second one works?

Comment: You might want to check [ascii code 97](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-a-minuscule-ascii-code-97.html) which seems to be `'a'`. And 26 might have something to do with the number of characters in the alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key used for the Vigenere cypher is supposed to be all letters. The first expression converts the string into an array of offsets, `0` for `a`, `1` for `b`, etc. 97 is the ASCII code for `'a'`.  It would be more readable to write:

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i < n; i++) {
    if (!isalpha((unsigned char)key[i])) {
        printf("key '%s' must contain only letters\n", key);
        return 1;
    }
    key[i] = tolower((unsigned char)key[i]);
    key[i] = key[i] - 'a';
}
```

For the second expression, if the character `txt[k]` is a lower case letter, `printf("%c", (((txt[k] - 97) + (key[k % l])) % 26 + 97));` computes and prints the transposed letter by adding the shift value (each character in `key` is used as a shift value one after the other, shifting by `0` for `a`, `1` for `b` etc.). Here are the steps:

- The program computes the letter index `txt[k] - 97`, `97` being the ASCII code for `'a'`,
- it then adds the shift value `key[k % l]`, cycling the values in `key` in a circular fashion,
- it takes the modulo 26 to get a letter index between 0 and 25.
- it finally adds `97`, the ASCII value of `'a'` to convert the index back into a lowercase letter.

It would be less redundant and more readable to write it this way:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; txt[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    int c = (unsigned char)txt[i];
    if (isupper(c)) {
        c = (c - 'A' + key[j++ % l]) % 26 + 'A';
    } else
    if (islower(c)) {
        c = (c - 'a' + key[j++ % l]) % 26 + 'a';
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

Also note that `argv[1]` should not be passed to `strlen()` before checking that enough arguments have been passed on the command line.

Here is a modified version of the program:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("missing key argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    string key = argv[1];
    int klen = strlen(key);
    if (klen == 0) {
        printf("key cannot be empty\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < klen; i++) {
        if (!isalpha((unsigned char)key[i])) {
            printf("key '%s' must contain only letters\n", key);
            return 1;
        }
        key[i] = tolower((unsigned char)key[i]) - 'a';
    }

    string txt = GetString();
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; txt[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        int c = (unsigned char)txt[i];
        if (isupper(c)) {
            c = (c - 'A' + key[j++ % klen]) % 26 + 'A';
        } else
        if (islower(c)) {
            c = (c - 'a' + key[j++ % klen]) % 26 + 'a';
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "unsigned char" is this important to add or ?

Comment: @kryin10: `islower()` and friends is only defined for the values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF`. If the `char` type is signed by default on your system, which is most probable, and if you type some extended characters such as `é`, these have a negative value for which `islower()` has undefined behavior. Casting the the `char` arguments as `(unsigned char)` is the standard way to avoid this problem.

Comment: thanks for the help. I think the program doesn't skip the space. I tried adding if isn't space and ' ' line but it doesn't seem to be working. any tips for that?

Comment: @kryin10: what do you mean by *the program doesn't skip the space*? any character in the string that is not a letter is output unchanged.

Comment: sorry for confusing. I mean, spaces gotta be ignored. only letters should be considered by the program. || Key given as "abc", text "AAA aaa" -> output ->  ABC bca

Comment: @kryin10: That's exactly the behavior I get with the above code.  What do you observe?

Comment: the output should be "ABC abc" the spaces must be ignored.  I couldn't explain the problem very well

Comment: @kryin10: OK, the index into the key must not change for ignored characters. I shall fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
key[i] = key[i] - 97;
```

That line's use is to give key[i], which value represents the value of a caracter in ascii it's index in our alphabet. Then, 'a' will be given the value 0, 'b' the value 1 .... , and 'z' the value 25.

As for the second line,

```
printf("%c", (((txt[k] - 97) + (key[k % l])) % 26 + 97))
```

it prints the caracter which's ascii value is

```
(((txt[k] - 97) + (key[k % l])) % 26 + 97))
```

The substraction of 97 has the same purpose as explained above.

The % 26 is the modulus, ie the remainder of ((txt[k] - 97) + (key[k % l])) when divided per 26 (integer division). Then, 97 is added again to convert the order, or index of the result into a corresponding ascii value.
This page might give you some more insight about the character representation in C.

As for the meaning of k,i and l, I let you grasp the inner functionning of the cypher by yourself, but the whole encryption happens in the second line you wished an explanation for.

PS : The parts with '65' are just the same, but with uppercase letters, since 'A' value in ascii is 65.